# ms-outlook uri scheme no longer working for xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin, outlook

Last week I implemented the ms-outlook url scheme into my xamarin app so that it can open outlook and start a new draft. For iOS, I did `await Launcher.OpenAsync("ms-outlook://compose?to=example@example.com");` and for Android I did `await Launcher.OpenAsync("ms-outlook://emails/new?to=example@mail.com");`
But now, though it still works in iOS, Outlook crashes when trying to open in Android. It opens fine if I just use the basic uri (ms-outlook://) but crashes if I try to start a draft (ms-outlook://emails/new?...).
Like I said, I'm quite certain this was working before, has anyone else run into this?

Here's what the log is giving me:

```
Error (24068) / AndroidRuntime: Process: com.microsoft.office.outlook, PID: 24068
Error (24068) / AndroidRuntime: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND dat=mailto:xxxx.xxxxxxx@xxxxx.xxxx pkg=com.microsoft.office.outlook }
Error (24068) / AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1968)
Error (24068) / AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1622)
Error (24068) / AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4564)
Error (24068) / AndroidRuntime:     at com.microsoft.intune.mam.client.app.MAMActivity.startActivityForResultReal(MAMActivity.java:306)
Error (24068) / AndroidRuntime:     at com.microsoft.intune.mam.client.app.offline.OfflineActivityBehavior.startActivityForResult(OfflineActivityBehavior.java:389)
Error (24068) / AndroidRuntime:     at com.microsoft.intune.mam.client.app.MAMActivity.startActivityForResult(MAMActivity.java:262)
Error (24068) / AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
Error (24068) / AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4883)
Error (24068) / AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4851)
Error (24068) / AndroidRuntime:     at com.acompli.acompli.DeepLinkActivity.d(DeepLinkActivity.java:209)
Error (24068) / AndroidRuntime:     at com.acompli.acompli.DeepLinkActivity.e(DeepLinkActivity.java:185)
Error (24068) / AndroidRuntime:     at com.acompli.acompli.DeepLinkActivity.lambda$Wcjak92AO1n3d8wWWz1A5V2GfN8(Unknown Source:0)
Error (24068) / AndroidRuntime:     at com.acompli.acompli.-$$Lambda$DeepLinkActivity$Wcjak92AO1n3d8wWWz1A5V2GfN8.onChanged(Unknown Source:4)
Error (24068) / AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:131)
Error (24068) / AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:149)
Error (24068) / AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:307)
Error (24068) / AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:50)
Error (24068) / AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$1.run(LiveData.java:91)
Error (24068) / AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
Error (24068) / AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
Error (24068) / AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
Error (24068) / AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
Error (24068) / AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
Error (24068) / AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
Error (24068) / AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
Error (24685) / propClient: PropClient failed to load
Error (24068) / CrashHelper: Uncaught error
Error (24068) / CrashHelper: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND dat=mailto:xxxx.xxxxxxx@xxxxx.xxxx pkg=com.microsoft.office.outlook }
Error (24068) / CrashHelper:    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1968)
Error (24068) / CrashHelper:    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1622)
Error (24068) / CrashHelper:    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4564)
Error (24068) / CrashHelper:    at com.microsoft.intune.mam.client.app.MAMActivity.startActivityForResultReal(MAMActivity.java:306)
Error (24068) / CrashHelper:    at com.microsoft.intune.mam.client.app.offline.OfflineActivityBehavior.startActivityForResult(OfflineActivityBehavior.java:389)
Error (24068) / CrashHelper:    at com.microsoft.intune.mam.client.app.MAMActivity.startActivityForResult(MAMActivity.java:262)
Error (24068) / CrashHelper:    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
Error (24068) / CrashHelper:    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4883)
Error (24068) / CrashHelper:    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4851)
Error (24068) / CrashHelper:    at com.acompli.acompli.DeepLinkActivity.d(DeepLinkActivity.java:209)
Error (24068) / CrashHelper:    at com.acompli.acompli.DeepLinkActivity.e(DeepLinkActivity.java:185)
Error (24068) / CrashHelper:    at com.acompli.acompli.DeepLinkActivity.lambda$Wcjak92AO1n3d8wWWz1A5V2GfN8(Unknown Source:0)
Error (24068) / CrashHelper:    at com.acompli.acompli.-$$Lambda$DeepLinkActivity$Wcjak92AO1n3d8wWWz1A5V2GfN8.onChanged(Unknown Source:4)
Error (24068) / CrashHelper:    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:131)
Error (24068) / CrashHelper:    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:149)
Error (24068) / CrashHelper:    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:307)
Error (24068) / CrashHelper:    at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:50)
Error (24068) / CrashHelper:    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$1.run(LiveData.java:91)
Error (24068) / CrashHelper:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
Error (24068) / CrashHelper:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
Error (24068) / CrashHelper:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
Error (24068) / CrashHelper:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
Error (24068) / CrashHelper:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
Error (24068) / CrashHelper:    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
Error (24068) / CrashHelper:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: What is reported in `logcat` during the Outlook crash?

Comment: Just updated with the log

Comment: @Christopher, Yes, I can reproduce your issue at my side, but I can not find one way to do, I think the outlook scheme Url is not correct, so It will crash when it try to start a new draft.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but it's strange that it was working for a little while. Maybe they changed the scheme.